# coregraphics layers vs core animation layers

Tags: ios

I have confusion regarding that coregraphics layers are same as core animation layers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Not even close. CoreGraphics has transparency layers, which are basically just a way for you to make a series of drawing calls, and put a shadow under all of them as if they were one drawing call (it's possible it does things other than shadows too, but that's all I've used them for). CoreAnimation layers are *completely* different, they are the basic building block for rendering things to the screen. They're what UIView's are built on top of.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If I want to create an image using coregraphics which has some border, an image in between and text on bottom. I want to do all these three things on transparency layers so is it valid? And now I want to animate this image like juggle border, image in between, text using core animation, for that I have to specify calayers again? How coregraphics and core animation can work together?

Comment: I don't see why you need transparency layers at all for that drawing.

Comment: because after drawing I want to animate them or later if user wants to change color of border or text. Thats why I am asking about layers. I am assuming layers weather its in coregraphics or core animation is like we have in photoshop keep drawing on layers and if you dont want any part turn off that layer.

Comment: Basically I am new to ios graphics and animation, I got stucke with a project in which I have to create animation similar to www.discovr.info ios app. Parent circle with some text or image in between, when tapped child circles with some details comes out of it and when child circle is tapped it expands to show details. Thats what I am trying to accomplish. There are many tutorials and videos available regarding core animation and quartz2d and I am trying to study them but the only problem is tight deadline and I dont know how to speed up this in depth topic learning.

Comment: Hi Mr.Kevin, please can you help me little bit in my tight scenario.